# Mapper mapped class could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class PartCar->partcar could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'partcar'
```

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'USER'

    user_id = Column(Integer)
    passport_number = Column(String(8), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_email = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    user_name = Column(String(20), nullable=False)

    carHave = relationship('Car', secondary='caruser')


class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car'

    car_number = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    userHave = relationship('User', secondary='caruser')
    partHave = relationship('Part', secondary='partcar')


class Part(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'part'

    part_name = Column(String(20), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    carHave = relationship('Car', secondary='partcar')


class CarUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'caruser'

    user_passport_number = Column(String(8), ForeignKey('USER.passport_number'))
    car_number = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('car.car_number'))
    car_model = Column(String(20), nullable=False)


class PartCar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'partcar'

    part_car_number = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('car.car_number'))
    part_name = Column(String(20), ForeignKey('part.part_name'))
    part_price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your **PartCar table**, **doesn't have a primary key**, for which sqlalchemy is raising an error.

Flask-SQLAlchemy requires a primary key because the [SQLAlchemy ORM requires a primary key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/11/faq/ormconfiguration.html#faq-mapper-primary-key):

> The SQLAlchemy ORM, in order to map to a particular table, needs there
> to be at least one column denoted as a primary key column.
>
> Most ORMs require that objects have some kind of primary key defined
> because the object in memory must correspond to a uniquely
> identifiable row in the database table.